# Error with shell test conditions

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu

Can't get this to run. I'm sure I'm doing something wrong and I'm sure I'm overlooking something.

```sh
a=3

echo "Type in the first Grade Number."
read num1;
echo "Type in the Second Grade Number."
read num2;
echo "Type in the third Grade Number."
read num3;

echo \($num1 + $num2 + $num3\)/$a | bc
read num;

if [ $num-lt 79 ]
then
echo "The Grade Number is an C."

elif [ $num-lt 89 ]
then
echo "The grade number is an B."

elif [ $num-lt 99 ]
then
echo "Your grade number is an A."

elif [ $num-lt 60 ]
then
echo "You have a failing number"
fi
```

Comment: Note that no-one will ever be reported as having a failing grade; they'll be given a C grade at worst.  And those A+ students who score an average of 100 will be annoyed to be given no grade.  Also note that `read num` will require the user to retype the answer given by `bc`.  If you want to capture the answer from `bc`, use: `num=$(echo "($num1+$num2+$num3)/$a" | bc)` or equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

```
if [ $num-lt 79 ]
```

You *need* a space between the `$num` and `-lt`. Without that, it's the two-argument form of expression. As per the `bash` man page, the two-argument form is evaluated thus:

> If the first argument is `!`, the expression is true if and only if the second argument is null.  If the first argument is one of the unary conditional operators listed above under CONDITIONAL EXPRESSIONS, the expression is true if the unary test is true.  ***If the first argument is not a valid unary conditional operator, the expression is false.***

---

There are a few other issues with your script you may want to look at as well.

First, you don't need `;` characters at the end of your `read` statements. They're not damaging but they are superfluous.

Second, you appear to output the average of the three grades then ask for another number which is checked for grades. I would have thought the average itself would be a better measure:

```
num=$(echo "($num1 + $num2 + $num3) / $a" | bc)
```

Thirdly, your logic means that a failing grade is never output. And number less than `60` would have already been caught by the initial test for less than `79`. A better approach would be to check the boundaries in order, with something like:

```
if [ $num -lt 60 ] ; then
    echo "You failed!"
elif [ $num -lt 80 ] ; then
    echo "You got a C, just made it."
elif [ $num -lt 90 ] ; then
    echo "You got a B, not bad."
elif [ $num -lt 100 ] ; then
    echo "You got an A, excellent."
else
    echo "You got an A, perfect score."
fi
```

Comment: How many times do you suppose this is a duplicate question?  And can we actually find a master question to make this a duplicate of?

Comment: @Jonathan, searching ... There are plenty without spaces after the `if` or after the `[` but it's damn hard to search for punctuation on the net, one reason why I gave up on Perl :-)

Comment: Agreed with difficulty.  I found [Errors from `if` and `else` statementsin shell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2410839/help-with-if-statements-and-else-newbie/2410878#2410878) — which needed some cleanup; it is for `[1: command not found` which is close...and its from 2010.